# PHP Memcache curr items

Tags: php, memcached

I was wondering if 'curr_items' in the memcache stats is the number of stored keys ?
From my testing , curr_items returned for me a higher number then the counter I've used to count the number of memcache keys by getting all the keys and counting it.

Can someone confirm that curr_items isn't the number of keys and what does curr_items represents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known behavior of memcached. Quoting :

> Expiration in memcached is lazy. In general, an item cannot be known
>   to be expired until something looks at it.

see [Why Isn't curr_items Decreasing When Items Expire?](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#Why_Isn%27t_curr_items_Decreasing_When_Items_Expire?)